# In jQuery, what does `this.selector` mean in `$(document).on('click', this.selector, ...)`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, selector

In a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/rejas/imagelightbox/blob/master/src/imagelightbox.js#L352)

I saw expression like this:

```
    $( document ).on( 'click', this.selector, this.startImageLightbox);
```

I know what `$("div").click(callback)` mean, but the whole expression above, especially `this.selector` looks quite confusing to me.

What does the `this` here mean?

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @epascarello I saw the documentation, but the `this` here is not very clear..

Comment: The `this` depends on the context this line is in.  `this` is the "context" the code is currently being run in.

Comment: @hanfeisun Looks like you need to look at OOP JavaScript to understand scoping of `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a property of the jQuery object(Inside the plugin method `this` refers to the jQuery object), which is the `selector` used to find the element.

Ex:

```
$('div').selector -> div
$('div input').selector -> div input
$('div').find('input').selector -> div input
```

So the said code is used to register a delegated event handler targeting the element on which the plugin was initialized

Answer (score 0):

**`.on("click", "selector", callback)` vs. `.click()`**

`.click()` attached a handler directly to the chosen selector. That means that any events that originate from that selector or one of its children will trigger the callback.

`.on("click", "selector", callback)` attaches the handler to the body. Because all elements are children here, everything will be a match. However, the second argument "selector" will filter out everything but that. This is especially useful if you are adding elements to your page after load has completed because you don't have to then attach handlers to the new element. The handler on the document will handle everything.

**this.selector**

This jQuery plugin stores the selector you provide as a property. `this` refers to the plugin, and `this.selector` refers to that property. The value that is being passed to the `.on()` function could be almost anything. For example `".classname"` or `"#elementId"`.